# Ubuntu 12.04 GUI does not start on boot, hangs on purple loading screen with Ubuntu logo and five dots

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, kernel, boot-repair

It started like this: I wanted to install Adobe Reader (.bin file) via Terminal. After I created a folder for installation files and started the whole process I suddenly realized that I don't even have enough disk space. After few seconds the system became very slow, so I closed the running applications and hit reboot. Well, after rebooting I faced the problem I wrote in the title. No response for hitting Esc button, but Ctrl+Alt+F1 worked, so I rebooted again and switched to recovery mode, where I used dpkg and clean, even went to root and deleted a couple of files, for example the Adobe Reader install file and the folder installation files, because I thought after making some space on my hdd and rebooting, there will be no problems. Well, it did not work. After this I tried to remove all unused kernel headers images, modules with the same exact blue code in this article: http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/ After reboot, the same. Then I prepared a USB live boot "cd" for Ubuntu 12.04 and booted with that. In that GUI I decided to run boot-repair, followed the instructions and got this report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5654068/ The problem is still the same as indicated in the title. I don't know if the problem is really with the boot itself or something else, but I really appreciate any help! This is the only operation system I use on this notebook and it worked without boot problems since 6 months. Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. The Boot-Repair log indicates that your system partition (sda1) is still 98% full. I recommend you make at least 10GB free space. (eg , you can transfer some documents/videos/images to a USB disk or else).
2. Then, if still not good, you may have a broken/missing system file. You can fix them this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation